# When using ViewPager with Fragments, the fragments are destroyed upon swipe

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

My application has a ViewPager whose adapter returns three Fragments. 
Each Fragment loads a list of data from Web in the onCreateView.
So let's call these fragments A, B, C.

Once the activity containing the viewPager is open, Fragments A and B are loaded.
But only A is visible now.
So if I swipe to the right, then B is visible and C is loaded behind the scene.
If I swipe to right again, then C is visible.
The problem is that, fragment A's onDestroyView() is called and all its loaded data is gone!
So if I come back to fragment A, then A's onCreateView() is called again and A's data is loaded from the web again.

Is it a default behaviour of ViewPager when using it with Fragment?
Is it possible to keek the fragment alive (by not calling onDestroyView()) even while it is not visible?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try:

```
yourViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2)
```

where 2 is the amount of pages to keep in memory on either side of the current page.